# Unidirectional OneToOne foreign primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm restricted by the below preexisting schema definition

```
CREATE TABLE `owner` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `owned` (
  `owner_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`owner_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_blabla` FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`) REFERENCES `owner` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I want to create a UNIDIRECTIONAL OneToOne relationship reflecting the above, and have so far come up with the below

```
@Entity
class Owner implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Owned owned;

}

@Entity
class Owned implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "owner_id")
    private Long ownerId;

}
```

However, when autogenerating a schema from the above JPA entity definition the constraint isn't generated

```
CREATE TABLE `owner` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `owned` (
  `owner_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`owned_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

What am I missing?

Comment: *"I want to create a UNIDIRECTIONAL OneToOne relationship reflecting the above, and have so far come up with the below"* ... but that doesn't seem to be what you're doing at all.  Rather it seems that you are describing a (bidirectional) one-to-one relationship with a shared primary key (so that the "child" table uses its primary key as a foreign key to the "parent" table).  The use of the `@MapsId` annotation is explainined in this blog post: http://vard-lokkur.blogspot.com/2014/05/onetoone-with-shared-primary-key.html

Comment: @scottb Indeed you are right and doing as outlined in the link appears to work fine, thanks. If you want some of those sweet stackoverflow points you can copy paste the blow post and I'll mark that as accepted.